# web.config - read custom section, change attribute and save it

Tags: c#, xml, web-config

I'm trying to access a specific custom section of a web.config file then change the section attribute value and save it

this us my config file:

```
<custom.viewpoint>
    <!-- ********** Repository ********** -->
    <application type="custom.Tablet.ReaderApplication, custom.Tablet">
      <content-set>
        <publications include="Periodical" default="AJCLI">
      </content-set>
    </application>
    <!-- ********** Security ********** -->
    <web.authentication enabled="false">
      <session persist="true" expiration="30.00:00:00" />
    </web.authentication>
<custom.viewpoint>
```

what I'm trying to do is access the web.authentication attribute enable it from true to false and vice versa. I want to do this for testing purposes, instead of going to each folder and changing this attribute to false I want to be able to do it from a program then when I'm done testing I want to turn it back on when done with testing.

I found this code to access section but isn't working for me. Any help is appreciated.

```
var configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
var section = (ConnectionStringsSection)configuration.GetSection("connectionStrings");
section.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString = "Data Source=...";
configuration.Save();



var config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/AppFolder");
var sectionx = config.GetSection("custom.viewpoint");

I don't know how to access the nodes from here
```